# Getting data from a range of values in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get a range of numbers depending on what the user inputs. 
I have customer.js which has the customer name and shoe size and what I would like is to get a range of shoe sizes depending
on what the user puts in.

For example. A user puts in the first textbox 5 and in the second textbox 9 I want the customers that is between 5 and 9, 
but also including 5 and 9 to be displayed.

I've only gotten as far as this.

my html

```
<form id="shoe_size">
    <label for="size">Enter sizes</label>
    <input type="text" name="size1" class="size1">
    <input type="text" name="size2" class="size2">
    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="submit">
</form>
```

my jquery

```
$('#shoe_size').on('submit', function(){
    var size1 = $('.size1').val();
    var size2 = $('.size2').val();

    $('.table tr').each(function(){
        var size = 'false';
        $(this).each(function(){
            if(size1 <= size2){
                found = 'true';
            }
        })

        if(size == 'true'){
            $(this).show();
        }else{
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the question? How is this behaving? Can you create a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Can you please give me the table tr td you are searching for? It will be lot more easier to get the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I am recreating your problem and solving it (Because your question is not clear | please give me your table and I will try to code according to it. Till then I am using an example table)
Let's you have a table like this.
`table to search`

```
<table>
  <tr size="10" >
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr size="11" >
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr size="12" >
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr size="13" >
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr size="14" >
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Let's user has submitted your form to get between 
any size range

`Jquery`

```
$('#shoe_size').on('submit', function(){
  var size1 = $('.size1').val();
  var size2 = $('.size2').val();

  $("table tr").each(function(){
     var tr_size = $(this).attr("size");
     if(tr_size >= size1 && tr_size <= size2){
         $(this).show();
     }else{
         $(this).hide();
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: that was it. Thank you so much. I really really appreciate it.

Comment: Nice to have you in 

Answer (score 0):

I know, the question *has* been answered. I just wanted to play around with a slighly shorter approach without a submit button:

```js
// quickly generate some sample data ...
var shoes=[[4,'wht','dda'],
[4,'red','aaa'],[7,'blk','aba'],
[5,'blu','ca'],[4,'red','db'],
[9,'grn','z'],[8,'yel','g']];
$('.shoetable tbody').append('<tr><td>'
+shoes.map(sh=>sh.join('</td><td>')).join('</td></tr><tr><td>')+'</td></tr>');

// and now: do the magic ...
$('input').keyup(()=>{
  var mi=$('.size1').val()-0||0;
  var ma=$('.size2').val()-0||1000;
  $('.shoetable tbody tr:gt(0)').each((i,tr)=>{
      var s=$('td:eq(0)',tr).text()-0;
      $(tr).toggle(s>=mi&&s<=ma);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="shoe_size">
<label for="size">Show sizes between</label>
<input type="text" name="size1" class="size1" size="3"> and
<input type="text" name="size2" class="size2" size="3">
</form>
<table class="shoetable"><tr>
 <th>size</th><th>color</th><th>model</th>
</tr></table>
```

Answer (score -1):

As far I'm understanding you code, you should change the following line

`found = 'true';`

to

`size = 'true'`

because you are checking `size == 'true'` in your code later, and also `found` is not declared anywhere in your code

Comment: As far as I know each() function is asynchronous. So, It might not work.